# How can I determine whether a void * pointer points to a objective-c object or a c++ object at runtime

Tags: c++, objective-c, runtime, respondstoselector

I have searched around for a while, but surprised that no one ever popped this question, so here I go:

I have a Objective-C method that takes an id argument. Now I want to use `respondsToSelector:` to determine if it is valid for following actions, if it is not not I have a backup plan for it. (Which is not `ASSERT(0)` :P)

So, when someone tries to mess up with me and pass an `(id)someC++Object`, I've got a big crash, of course.

My question is simply: Can I make a C++ object fail a `respondsToSelector:` safely so that I can use my backup plan (punching the coder in the face for one)?

Comment: Nope. I'd put that as an answer but somebody else can probably explain it better. Short answer is still "nope."

Comment: 'id' is nice but in an environment where I had to worry about that kind of code abuse, I'd require the parameter to have a known type or at least implement a defined protocol.

Comment: @user - The way to keep type info is *not* to pass a `void*` pointer. You just cannot have it both ways - there is no type safety for typeless data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you can't.

At least, not reliably and not in any sane way.   Nor, frankly, should bother;   that level of defensive programming is utterly futile in the face of a C based language.

At the least, you would need to:

- validate that the pointer is pointing to accessible memory
- pointing to a current allocation
- the first address sized chunk points to an Objective-C class (including derived classes, possibly)

In general, any code that makes heavy use of `isKindOfClass:` and `respondsToSelector:` (outside of the delegation pattern) is quite atypical to the norms of Objective-C design patterns.

Or, to put it another way, you have a static type checking compiler that is quite good at checking lots of validity parameters at compile time.  Use it.

Comment: I was implementing some event mechanism compatible with both ObjC and C++, a same interface with two slightly different workarounds. Well, I have done some more searching and found some hacky way to do this but the efficiency is unbearable. Maybe it's time to let go :(